# finding paths in graphs with integer stack or array

Tags: python, graph, stack, depth-first-search

Given a graph (ordered DAG) represented using an adjacency matrix

```
g = [
        [0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ]
```

I wrote the following to figure out all the longest paths in the graph starting from the first node, node 0.

```
from collections import deque
stack = deque()
stack.append([0])
current_longest = 1
paths = []
N = len(g[0])

while stack:
    cur_path = stack.pop()
    print(cur_path)
    last_node = cur_path[-1]

    any_n = False
    for new_node in range(last_node + 1, N):
        if g[last_node][new_node] == 1:
            any_n = True
            stack.append(cur_path + [new_node])

    if any_n == False:
        if len(cur_path) > current_longest:
            nmb_paths = 1
            paths = []
            paths.append(cur_path) 
            current_longest = len(cur_path)
        elif len(cur_path) == current_longest:
            nmb_paths += 1
            paths.append(cur_path)    
print(f"paths = {paths}")
```

The output of this:

```
[0]
[0, 2]
[0, 2, 3]
[0, 2, 3, 5]
[0, 2, 3, 5, 6]
[0, 2, 3, 4]
[0, 2, 3, 4, 6]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 1, 3, 5]
[0, 1, 3, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 3, 4]
[0, 1, 3, 4, 6]
paths = [[0, 2, 3, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6], [0, 1, 3, 4, 6]]
```

but I am now trying to figure out if I can do this without the luxury of an array stack. So if I can't store arrays as elements of the stack, I can only use an integer stack or a normal array. I am stuck on this, I think it's a matter of keeping track of the length of the list, as it grows, storing each path, and if it doesn't grow, storing the path, but a little stumped atm, any hints?

Answer (score 0):

not much interest, but thought I'd put up my solution anyway, in case it helps anyone (I was implementing this in C so it was a pain having to write an ArrayStack) this was my prototype:

```
g = [
        [0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ]

N = len(g[0])

nmb_paths = 1
current_longest = 1
paths = []
array = [0]
current_length = 1
visited = [0] * N
visited[0] = 1
pred = [-1] * N


while current_length > 0:
    last_node = array[current_length-1]

    any_n = False
    new_node = last_node + 1

    print('paths = ', paths)

    while not any_n and new_node < N:
        if g[last_node][new_node] == 1 and visited[new_node] != 1:
            if pred[new_node] != last_node:
                pred[new_node] = last_node
                any_n = True

                array.append(new_node)
                visited[new_node] = 1
                current_length += 1
                last_node = new_node

                if current_length > current_longest:
                    paths = []
                    app = array.copy()
                    paths.append(app)
                    current_longest = current_length
                    nmb_paths = 1
                elif current_length == current_longest:
                    app = array.copy()
                    paths.append(app)
                    nmb_paths += 1

        new_node+=1

    if any_n == False:
        final = array[current_length - 1]
        del array[current_length-1]
        visited[final] = 0
        for j in range(final+1, N):
            pred[j] = -1
        current_length -= 1
```

the progression of paths:

```
paths =  []
paths =  [[0, 1]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6], [0, 2, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6], [0, 2, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6], [0, 2, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6], [0, 2, 3, 5, 6]]
paths =  [[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], [0, 1, 3, 5, 6], [0, 2, 3, 4, 6], [0, 2, 3, 5, 6]]
```